# CherryPy Logging: How do I configure and use the global and application level loggers?

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

I'm having trouble with logging.  I'm running CherryPy 3.2 and I've been reading through the docs [here](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ConfigAPI), but haven't found any examples of how to configure a local log file for output and how to write to it.

Raspberry.py:

```
import socket
import sys
import cherrypy

app_roots = {
                # Sean's laptop dev environment.
                "mylaptop": "/home/src/local-mydomain.com/py",

                # Hosted dev environment.  
                "mydomain.com" : "/home/dev/src/py"
            }


hostname = socket.gethostname()
CherryPyLog = cherrypy.tree.mount().log

if hostname not in app_roots:
    CherryPyLog("The following hostname does not have an app_root entry in raspberry.py.  Exiting early.")
    sys.exit()

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
sys.path.append(app_roots[hostname])

import os
os.chdir(app_root)

# Setup for raspberry application logging.
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
log.access_file = "{0}/{1}.raspberry.access.log".format(app_roots[hostname],today.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M"))
log.error_file = "{0}/{1}.raspberry.error.log".format(app_roots[hostname],today.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M"))

#Testing logger
log("{0} -- Logger configured".format(today.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")))

import atexit
cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})

if cherrypy.__version__.startswith('3.0') and cherrypy.engine.state == 0:
    cherrypy.engine.start(blocking = False)
    atexit.register(cherrypy.engine.stop)

from web.controllers.root import RaspberryRequestHandler

application = cherrypy.Application(RaspberryRequestHandler(), script_name = None, config = None)
```

UPDATE:  Here's the code block that I ended up going with.

```
app_roots = {
                # Sean's laptop dev environment.
                "mylaptop": "/home/src/local-plottools.com/py",

                # Hosted dev environment.  
                "myDomain" : "/home/dev/src/py"
            }

import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()

import cherrypy
import sys
if hostname not in app_roots:
    cherrypy.log("The hostname {0} does not have an app_root entry in {1}.  Exiting early.".format(hostname,__file__))
    sys.exit()

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
sys.path.append(app_roots[hostname])

import os
os.chdir(app_roots[hostname])

from web.controllers.root import RaspberryRequestHandler

cherrypy.config.update({
    'log.access_file': "{0}/cherrypy-access.log".format(app_roots[hostname]),
    'log.error_file': "{0}/cherrypy.log".format(app_roots[hostname]),
    "server.thread_pool" : 10
})

# special case, handling debug sessions when quickstart is needed.
if __name__ == "__main__":

    cherrypy.config.update({
                                'log.screen': True, 
                                "server.socket_port": 8000
                            })
    cherrypy.quickstart(RaspberryRequestHandler())
    sys.exit()

# This configuration is needed for running under mod_wsgi.  See here:  http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModWSGI    
cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})

applicationLogName = "{0}/raspberry.log".format(app_roots[hostname])

from logging import handlers
applicationLogFileHandler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(applicationLogName, 'a', 10000000, 1000)

import logging
applicationLogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from cherrypy import _cplogging
applicationLogFileHandler.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)

cherrypy.log.error_log.addHandler(applicationLogFileHandler)

application = cherrypy.Application(RaspberryRequestHandler(), None)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplifying a bit:

```
import os
import socket
import sys

import cherrypy

app_roots = {
                # Sean's laptop dev environment.
                "mylaptop": "/home/src/local-mydomain.com/py",

                # Hosted dev environment.  
                "mydomain.com" : "/home/dev/src/py"
            }


hostname = socket.gethostname()
if hostname not in app_roots:
    cherrypy.log("The hostname %r does not have an app_root entry in "
                 "raspberry.py.  Exiting early." % hostname)
    sys.exit()

sys.path.append(app_roots[hostname])
os.chdir(app_root)

cherrypy.config.update({
    'environment': 'embedded',
    'log.access_file': "{0}/raspberry.access.log".format(app_roots[hostname]),
    'log.error_file': "{0}/raspberry.error.log".format(app_roots[hostname]),
    })

from web.controllers.root import RaspberryRequestHandler
application = cherrypy.tree.mount(RaspberryRequestHandler(), '/')
# Insert log changes here
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

If you want different logs per day, use a RotatingFileHandler as described at http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/Logging#CustomHandlers The important point I think you're missing is that you should muck about with app.log only *after* you've instantiated your app (e.g. via tree.mount(), as above), but *before* engine.start. That is, for the error log:

```
application = cherrypy.tree.mount(RaspberryRequestHandler(), '/')

log = application.log
log.error_file = ""

# Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the error log.
fname = "{0}/raspberry.error.log".format(app_roots[hostname])
h = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fname, 'a', 10000000, 1000)
h.setLevel(DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
log.error_log.addHandler(h)

cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Hope that helps...